# How to mix customised behaviour with Xcode UI pre-defined sprite when using Sprite Kit

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I got a hero and enemies sprites pre-defined via UI which I can invoke like:

```
let heroSprite = childNode(withName: HeroName) as! SKSpriteNode
heroSprite.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = HeroCategory
```

That works as my logic is within the SKScene subclass which implements SKScene.childNode(_)

Now I want to extract the hero logic into a reusable subclass of SKSprite without having to do everything programatically e.g.  assign texture, etc.

I want to get the benefit of building maps via UI but I want to have the benefits of Object Orientation like:

```
class Hero: SKSpriteNode { func heroCustomBehaviour(_) }
class Enemy: SKSpriteNode { func enemyCustomBehaviour(_) }
```

Or:

```
class Hero: SKNode { func heroCustomBehaviour(_) }
class Enemy: SKNode { func enemyCustomBehaviour(_) }
```

It would be nice if I could do that without passing the SKScene ( breaking dependency inversion )  to the subclass.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution which wasn't very clear in XCode UI

[image]

I can instantiate like:

```
childNode(withName: HeroName) as? MyCustomClass
```